# How to load configuration data in Tests project in .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, configuration-files

I've been looking around for an answer to an issue when trying to instantiate and run some methods of a controller class that uses a configuration file in a separate project. It happens also when trying to test my controller from a Testing xUnit Project.

Here is my controller class, which works totally fine by running the project that includes it:

```
public class MyController
{
    private static String Payload;
    private static String Endpoint;

    public MyController() {    
         Payload = $"grant_type=password" +
                   $"&client_id={MyConfigurationClass.AppSetting["JsonSection:clientid"]}" +
                   $"&client_secret={MyConfigurationClass.AppSetting["JsonSection:secret"]}" +
                   $"&username={MyConfigurationClass.AppSetting["JsonSection:user"]}" +
                   $"&password={MyConfigurationClass.AppSetting["JsonSection:password"]}";
         Endpoint = MyConfigurationClass.AppSetting["JsonSection:endpoint"];
    }

    public static string GetToken()
    {
        string HtmlResult = string.Empty;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(Endpoint, Payload);
        }
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(HtmlResult);
        return json.access_token;
    }

    public String DoSomething()
    {
        GetToken();         
        return "testing ok";
    }

    public class Token
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This controller class is supposed to get the configuration from a json file and use it when doing http calls to an external API.

Now when trying to instantiate MyController from a separate project I get an exception, here is my Test from a Testing project:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var controller = new MyController();
        var result = controller.DoSomething();
        //Assert
        Assert.Equal("testing ok", result);
    }
```

I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

Can anyone provide some help or documentation on how this should be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that adding the following NuGet libraries solves the issue partially:

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

After adding those libraries to my Testing Project I fixed the issue above, after that I had to manually copy the json file to my project and make sure to read it once in my tests:

```
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("myConfigurationClassFile.json")
        .Build();
    controller = new MyController();
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, it was just the way I found.

Comment: It is still not clear how config and controller are related. Could you share more about what MyConfigurationClass is doing?

Comment: All ASP.NET Core templates add this NuGet package. It's not Core specific either, you can add it to Full Framework projects as well. That's described in the documentation, tutorials, MSDN Magazine articles by the way. For example, [Essential .NET - Configuration in .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx).